# xmllint encodes special chars

Tags: bash, xmllint

This is my file (UTF-8 encoded):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar>Hello World äüö</bar>
</foo>
```

I would like to use `xmllint` to produce this result:

```
<bar>Hello World äüö</bar>
```

But every command prints encoded unicode characters:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//bar" file.xml
<bar>Hello World &#xE4;&#xFC;&#xF6;</bar>
$ xmllint --xpath "//bar" --encode utf-8 file.xml
<bar>Hello World &#xE4;&#xFC;&#xF6;</bar>
$ xmllint --xpath "//bar" --noenc file.xml
<bar>Hello World &#xE4;&#xFC;&#xF6;</bar>
```

Do you have any idea how to get the unencoded result? (I can not install other tools like xmlstarlet..).

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20907
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma
$ locale
LANG=C.utf8
LC_CTYPE="C.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.utf8"
LC_TIME="C.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="C.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="C.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.utf8"
LC_PAPER="C.utf8"
LC_NAME="C.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.utf8"
LC_ALL=
$ cat /etc/*-release
Rocky Linux release 8.8 (Green Obsidian)
```

Comment: all of your `xmllint` calls generate the desired result on my systems (cygwin, ubuntu); possible issue with your current locale settings? could you update the question with the output from `locale`?

Comment: @markp-fuso updated the question

Comment: If you're using a spec-compliant XML parser to read the generated data, it'll see your actual and requested output as 100% identical to each other. Consider fixing this on the consumer end.

Comment: well, I thought it would be something 'simple' like your console's locale settings but ... I reset all of my locale variables to your settings and still get the desired output; `locale v 20912` and `locale v 20913`, both compiled with the same set of libs as yours, except both of mine are missing `Expr`; does `cat file.xml` display the characters correctly? and with that I've exhausted my $0.02 worth of comments

Comment: My `xmllint --version` includes ICU (International Components for Unicode). Is it possible to upgrade your xmllint ? Also can you post the output of `ldd $(type -p xmllint)` ?

Comment: IIRC, this was fixed somewhat recently in libxml2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option seems to be `cat` internal shell command

Given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
  <B>Hello World äüö  &#xE4;&#xFC;&#xF6;</B>
</A>
```

Sending `cat <xpath expression>` to internal shell

```
printf "%s\n" "cat //B/text()" 'bye' |  xmllint --shell tmp.xml | grep -Ev '^([/]| -----)'
Hello World äüö  äüö
```

Issue looks related to `xmllint` version (`libxml2` version in the end). See details below

```
xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20914
```

Using `xmllint --shell`

```
echo "cat //B" | xmllint --shell tmp.xml 
/ > cat //B
 -------
<B>Hello World äüö  äüö</B>
```

`--noenc` and no xpath. `noenc`takes precedence over `noent` which makes sense, all characters in output are ascii.

```
xmllint --noenc tmp.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
  <B>Hello World &#xE4;&#xFC;&#xF6;  &#xE4;&#xFC;&#xF6;</B>
</A>
```

`--noent`(looks the default)

```
xmllint --noent tmp.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
  <B>Hello World äüö  äüö</B>
</A>
```

`--xpath` - `noenc` is ignored

```
xmllint --noenc --noent --xpath '//B' tmp.xml 
<B>Hello World äüö  äüö</B>

xmllint --xpath '//B' tmp.xml 
<B>Hello World äüö  äüö</B>
```

`--shell` - `noenc` is ignored on `cat` internal command and enforced on `xpath` one.

```
xmllint --shell --noenc tmp.xml 
/ > cat //B/text()
 -------
Hello World äüö  äüö
/ > xpath //B/text()
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 1 nodes:
1  TEXT
    content=Hello World #C3#A4#C3#BC#C3#B6  #C3#A4#C3#BC#C3#B6
```

ASCII encoding

```
xmllint --encode ASCII tmp.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<A>
  <B>Hello World &#228;&#252;&#246;  &#228;&#252;&#246;</B>
</A>
```

`lxml` pyhton module is also based on libxml so here's a one liner that does the same

```
python3 -c 'import sys; from lxml import etree;doc=etree.parse(sys.argv[1]); print(doc.xpath(sys.argv[2]))' tmp.xml '//B/text()'
```

text result

```
['Hello World äüö  äüö']
```

Serialazing **without indicating encoding**

```
python3 -c 'import sys; from lxml import etree;doc=etree.parse(sys.argv[1]); print(etree.tostring(doc.xpath(sys.argv[2])[0]).decode("utf-8"))' tmp.xml '//B'
<B>Hello World &#228;&#252;&#246;  &#228;&#252;&#246;</B>
```

Serialazing **with encoding**

```
python3 -c 'import sys; from lxml import etree;doc=etree.parse(sys.argv[1]); print(etree.tostring(doc.xpath(sys.argv[2])[0], encoding="utf-8").decode("utf-8"))' tmp.xml '//B'
<B>Hello World äüö  äüö</B>
```

Comment: Awesome, using cat in the xmllint shell solved the problem. Thank you very much!